# Как вырезать столбец из csv файла и сохранить в другой?

Tags: shell

Подскажите как вырезать  столбец из csv файла и сохранить в новый файл.

Номер столбца - третий,
Разделитель 《|》

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться либо awk:

```
awk -F'|' '{print $3}' file.csv > new-file
```

Либо cut:

```
cut -d'|' -f3 file.csv > new-file
```

А также powershell:

```
cat file.csv | %{ $_.split('|')[2] } > new-file
```